# Should I send 404 errors to bad bots scanning my website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, http-status-code-404

I have bad bots scanning my website everyday to check what framework or CMS I use and try to get in.
Example :

- /webmanage/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/browser/default/connectors/asp/connector.asp
- /cart/include/version.php
- /app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
- etc.

They receive a 404 error, and they try the next one.

Should I let them try and receive 404 errors, or send them no errors and an empty page to make these tests useless ? What would be the best practice ?